# How to debug why an Amazon S3 download in crontab is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, command-line, cron

I have a very simple script that I'm using to download a file from an Amazon S3 bucket and place it in a folder on my local machine:

```
aws s3 cp s3://sfbucket.bucket/sf_events.json /Users/Documents/data/sf_events.json
```

If I type this in command line, it works without issue. However, I want this script to run once a day automatically, so I'm trying to put it in crontab:

```
01 19 * * * aws s3 cp s3://sfbucket.bucket/sf_events.json /Users/Documents/data/sf_events.json
```

For some reason, this fails to run in crontab. Why might this not work?

Comment: can you post the error

Comment: Arun, There's no error, it just doesn't run.  Or is there a way to access the error log?

Comment: how did you set the cron, did you write in `crontab -e`

Comment: Yes, I wrote the command using crontab -e and verify that the command is there using crontab -l

Comment: what operating system are you using

Comment: mac OS.  I'm just using the built-in terminal on mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all to figure out why it's not working, you can redirect the output of the command.

you can redirect the output:

```
01 19 * * * aws s3 aws s3 cp s3://sfbucket.bucket/sf_events.json /Users/Documents/data/sf_events.json >> /Users/Arun/Learning/help-project/cron-help/logs2.txt 2>&1
```

this solution will not solve your problem, but it will show you the problem.

Solution:

this worked for me

```
01 19 * * * /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/aws s3 cp s3://sfbucket.bucket/sf_events.json /Users/Documents/data/sf_events.json >> /Users/Arun/Learning/help-project/cron-help/logs2.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205171/discussion-between-arun-k-and-diamondjoe12).

Comment: Messaged you in the chat